# Why clean glass fish admin console doesn't work?

Tags: java, macos, glassfish, glassfish-3, glassfish-4

> My system is:
>
> Mac os X 10.9 Mavericks
>
> Oracle JDK 7u45 (the latest)
>
> Glassfish 3 and Glassfish 4 is the same

I go to the download page of glass fish and download the zip.

i do init the glassfish domain using: *asadmin start-domain domain1*

Go to `localhost:4848` and the console still loading...

i review the glassfish log in this point, and the last message is:

> javax.enterprise.system.core.com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.adapter|_ThreadID=83;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|The Admin Console application is loaded.|#]

the message appears to be fine.

When i refresh the page (because doesn't refresh itself), it redirects me to `http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf` with status 404.

if i review again the glass fish log, the message is:

> org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet|_ThreadID=84;*ThreadName=Thread-2;|PWC6117: File "/Users/juvinao/glassfish4/glassfish/lib/install/applications/*_admingui/common/index.jsp" not found|#]

**this just happen in my mac, after the mavericks upgrade.**

in others computers and OSs, everything go fine.

i was googling for info about this issue, but even here in stack overflow i had found the answer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the only way that i resolved the issue, is that when the console redirect me to

`http://localhost:4848/common/index.jsf`

i put the url

`http://localhost:4848/login.jsf`

but always i have to do this. next i have access to login page and admin console.

Answer (score 0):

i had the same problem, but instead of console, my app was behaving like this.

solution: update "glassfish/glassfish/modules/javax.faces.jar" (2.2.0) with [2.2.4](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.4/javax.faces-2.2.4.jar)

still don't know why or in which way these things are linked...

Comment: i try it updating the javax.faces.jar to 2.2.4 version but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the file is not missing and you have enough rights to access it or maybe modify.

Comment: The next thing you should try is to run command: asadmin enable-secure-admin

Answer (score 0):

Disable Automatic Update Checks
Rename $GLASSFISH_INST/glassfish/modules/console-updatecenter-plugin.jar to console-updatecenter-plugin.jar.disabled

Comment: This post is being automatically flagged as low quality because it is so short. Would you mind expanding it by adding some text to explain how it solves the problem?